# What is the difference between colors and logColors in configuration field

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, coffeescript, karma-runner

I have a project based on angularjs and written with coffeescript. I am working to add unit tests to my project with karma and jasmine

Building my configuration file I found two way to specify colors in logging.

```
colors:true
```

and

```
logColors:true
```

What is the difference between colors and logColors?

How do I have to specify log level?

Comment: From what I can see they is no logColors option : https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: You're right. I should have taken that from some example like this https://github.com/xzyfer/fine-uploader-1/blob/master/karma.conf.coffee (not from that however I can't find the original). Probably it is referred to an other framework... sorry, silly question then

Answer (score 1):

You can specify:

- colors

> Type: Boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> Description: Enable or disable colors in the output (reporters and logs).

- logLevel

> Type: Constant
>
> Default: config.LOG_INFO
>
> Possible values:
>
> - config.LOG_DISABLE
> - config.LOG_ERROR
> - config.LOG_WARN
> - config.LOG_INFO
> - config.LOG_DEBUG
>
> Description: Level of logging.

From https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html